# Regx to remove output from last two dash

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I can have two inputs 1234-5-8888-8978 or 1234-8888-8978 i just want to remove string afterlast two dash(hypen).

input: 1234-5-8888-8978 
output: 1234-5 (remove content after last two hypen)
input: 1234-8888-8978
output: 1234 (remove content after last two hypen)

I am using something

```
echo "1234-5-8888-8978" | sed -n  's/.*\(-[0-9]*-[0-9]*$\)/\1/p'
-8888-8978

echo "1234-8888-8978" | sed -n  's/.*\(-[0-9]*-[0-9]*$\)/\1/p'
-8888-8978
```

But i want output exclude this pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the part before the hyphens:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)-[0-9]*-[0-9]*$/\1/' <<< "1234-5-8888-8978"
# => 1234-5 (POSIX BRE)
sed -E  's/(.*)-[0-9]*-[0-9]*$/\1/' <<< "1234-8888-8978"
# => 1234 (POSIX ERE)
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/aDthRF)

But it is more appropriate to just remove the last 2 parts between hyphens like

```
sed 's/-[0-9]*-[0-9]*$//' <<< "1234-5-8888-8978"
# => 1234-5 (POSIX BRE will suffice)
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/KJTede)

The `-[0-9]*-[0-9]*$` pattern matches a `-` followed with 0+ digits two times at the end of the string. It can be written as `(-[0-9]*){2}$` in the POSIX ERE syntax and as `\(-[0-9]*\)\{2\}$` in the POSIX BRE syntax.